# Windows Phone Calendar - Month view

Tags: windows-phone-7, calendar

I want to create a small app for Windows Phone, and it will based on calendar, so people can input dates etc. But I can't find control which provides me calendar month view. I only saw that there is DatePicker, but that is not exactly what I'm looking for.

Is there control like that for Windows Phone?

Thanks, 
Ned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this might be a good calendar control for your needs: https://wpcontrols.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe more sophisticated but not for free (99$): Telerik's Controls
http://www.telerik.com/products/windows-phone/overview/all-controls.aspx

But'll get a lot of controls all out of a single source ;)